# JS/Ajax refresh PHP include inside a div on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 2 php pages:

`reviewtickets.php` and `reviewtickets_history.php`

on `reviewtickets.php` i have:

```
<div class="tabcontent" id="ticket_history-1">
<?php include("reviewtickets_history.php?seq=".$_GET["seq"]."&type=history");?>
</div>
```

and then `reviewtickets_history.php` has select queries to a MySQL Database on it and a HTML form.

i want to be able to reload the `reviewtickets_history.php` include when the form has been submitted but without refreshing the whole `reviewtickets.php` page

UPDATE:

My PHP echoed form:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="reviewtickets_history.php?seq='.$_GET["seq"].'&type='.$_GET["type"].'" id="ticket_update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#666666"><font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>Record History / Make Progress</strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="17%"><strong>Internal Message?</strong></td>
            <td width="15%"><select name="internal_message" id="internal_message">
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
            </select></td>
            <td width="10%"><strong>For Agent</strong></td>
            <td width="58%">'.$internal_message_agent_list.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><textarea name="ticket_update" id="ticket_update" style="width:100%; height:160px;"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><strong>File(s):</strong> <input type="file" name="ticket_update_files[]" multiple="multiple" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><strong>Time Start:</strong>
            <input name="timestart_date" type="text" value="'.date("Y-m-d").'" onClick="ds_sh(this);" readonly size="15" maxlength="50" />
            <input type="text" name="timestart_time" size="10" value="'.date("H:i:s").'" />
            <strong>Time End:</strong>
            <input name="timeend_date" type="text" value="'.date("Y-m-d").'" onClick="ds_sh(this);" readonly size="15" maxlength="50" />
            <input type="text" name="timeend_time" size="10" value="'.date("H:i:s").'" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input type="checkbox" name="send_ticket_update_email" value="Y" checked="checked" /> If this box is checked an &quot;Ticket Update Email&quot; will be sent to the contacts</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="right">
            <input type="hidden" name="contact" id="contact" value="'.$ticket["contact"].'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="company" id="company" value="'.$ticket["company"].'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ticketnumber" id="ticketnumber" value="'.$_GET["seq"].'" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form via AJAX, and then refresh the `div` with another AJAX call.  I'm using an example form to post, but it should be pretty close to what is needed.

The HTML:

```
<form id='exampleForm' action='' method='post'>

    <label for='fieldOne'>Field One</label>:
    <input type='text' id='fieldOne'>

    <label for='fieldTwo'>Field One</label>:
    <input type='text' id='fieldTwo'>

    <!-- You should sanitize any user input.  Look into htmlspecialchars() -->
    <input type='hidden' id='seq' value='<?php echo $_GET['seq']; ?>'>
    <input type='hidden' id='type' value='<?php echo $_GET['type']; ?>'>

    <input type='submit' id='formSubmit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formSubmit").click(function(e) {
      //Prevent the form from submitting, and taking you away from the page.
      e.preventDefault();

      // Using an example form to demonstrate the submit
      var fieldOne = $("#fieldOne").val(),
          fieldTwo = $("#fieldTwo").val(),
          seq = $("#seq").val(),
          type = $("#type").val();

      var theURL = "reviewtickets_history.php?seq="+seq+"&type="+type;

      var formData = "fieldOne="+fieldOne+"&fieldTwo="+fieldTwo;

        $.ajax({
          url : theURL,
          type: "POST",
          data : formData,
          /* Setting async to false makes sure the info is posted before refreshing the div */
          async:false,
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
          {
            $("#ticket_history-1").html(data);
          },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
          {
            $("#ticket_history-1").html("Something bad happened"); 
          }
      });

      //ajax call to refresh the div
      $.ajax({
        url : theURL,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
          $("#ticket_history-1").html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
          $("#ticket_history-1").html("Something bad happened"); 
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Side note:  the first post should be done with `async:false` to insure that the form is posted before refreshing the `div`.

Comment: will this happen after all my queries have been run on the reviewtickets_history.php page?

Comment: This would fire as soon as the button is clicked, though the actual form submission would take you away from the page.  I'm fixing that in my answer.

Comment: aha okk, so my form is on the reviewtickets_history.php page and so are the queries so i want to submit the form, run the queries first then refresh the include on the reviewtickets.php page

Comment: Post the form and I can get a more accurate answer here, but once you submit the form it's going to take you to whatever page is in the `action` attribute unless you stop the default behavior.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.  This would keep everything on the page the same, and only refresh the `div` on submit.  More info and I can update again to show the first ajax call too.

Comment: i want to be able to submit the form (on reviewtickets_history.php with the queries also on reviewtickets_history.php) and then refresh the PHP include (include 'reviewtickets_history.php';) on the reviewtickets.php page

Comment: Personally, I'd put the GET parameters in a hidden input field in the form.  Then construct the URL to post to before making the ajax call.  Do the same thing if you want the parameters in the refresh ajax call.  What does your form look like?

Comment: check my edit, my form is being echoed in PHP so it may look like there are some bits missing but there isnt :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44456/discussion-between-matthew-johnson-and-charlie)

Comment: Updated answer, moved to chat room if more help is needed.

Answer (score -1):

That's not how include works. It's local on serverside, you don't have to append the query arguments. Include takes path to the file that will be included and the included source will have access to global variables.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php